# Iterate over- and easilly modify datastructure

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to render an array of inputs out of data which would be fairly straightforward:

```js
const [myInputs, setMyInputs] = useState([{id: 1, value: 'foo'},{id: 2, value: 'bar'}, ...])

myInputs.map(({id, value}) => <input key={id} value={value} />
```

the problem is that If I want to add an `onChange` function I have to find my object, remove it from the array, make a new object with the new values and insert it at the same position, same for every other modification I want to make to my data.

Is there a better way to accomplish the same effect (have an iterable where I can modify each value individually)?

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this:

```
const [myInputs, setMyInputs] = useState({
  nameOfInput1: {
    id: 1, 
    value: 'foo'
  },
  nameOfInput2: {
    id: 2, 
    value: 'bar'
  }, 
})

Object.entries(myInputs).forEach(([key, field]) => (
    <input 
      key={field.id} 
      value={field.value} 
      onChange={(newValue) => setMyInputs({ ...myInputs, key: { ...field, value: newValue } })} 
    />
)
```

Answer (score -3):

Convert the array to key value pairs. For Example:

```
{id: 1, value: 'foo'},{id: 2, value: 'bar'}
```

will be

```
 const obj = {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}
```

So using the id you can delete, update or add the object.

```
delete obj[1]; //delete
obj[2] = 'new bar'; //update
obj[3] = 'new val'; //add
```

Also for rendering you can do `Object.keys(obj)` and map it to element.

Comment: works but an object is not indexed so this isn't ideal